# Having some error issues about designing a blog in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, blogs

I tried to use paperclip to include Images in my design of a blog. I keep getting the error : 
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in ArticlesController#create
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"} missing required keys: [:id]
Now, whenever I click on the submit button to create a new article, it says "Could not find article without id". I tried also accessing the view for the show page through a link and I could not.

Extracted source (around line #30):

Here is my Articles Controller

```
    class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 def index
  @articles = Article.all
 end
def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Comment.new
 @comment.article_id = @article.id
end
def new
 @article = Article.new
end
def create
 @article = Article.new(article_params)
 @article.save
 redirect_to article_path
end
def edit
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
def destroy
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 @article.destroy
 redirect_to articles_path
end
def update
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])
 @article.update(article_params)
 flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' Updated!"
 redirect_to article_path
end
def article_params
 params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :tag_list, :image)
end
end
```

Here is my articles Helper:

```
module ArticlesHelper
 def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, :tag_list, :image)
 end 
end
```

Here is my articles/show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @article.title %></h1>
  <p>
   Tags:
   <% @article.tags.each do |tag| %> <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag) %>
   <% end %>
    </p>
    <% if @article.image.exists? %>
     <p><%= image_tag @article.image.url %></p>
     <% end %>
     <p><%= @article.body %></p>
     <h3>Comments (<%= @article.comments.size %>)</h3>
     <%= render partial: 'articles/comment', collection: @article.comments %>
      <%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>
      <%= link_to "<< Back to Articles List", articles_path %>
       <%= link_to "delete", article_path(@article), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Really         delete the article?"} %>
        <%= link_to "edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
```

And here is my routes file

```
TheBlog::Application.routes.draw do
 root                  'static_pages#home'
 get 'help'          => 'static_pages#help'
 get 'about'         => 'static_pages#about'
 get 'contact'       => 'static_pages#contact'
 get 'signup'        => 'users#new'
 get 'login'         => 'sessions#new'
 post 'login'        => 'sessions#create'
 delete 'logout'     => 'sessions#destroy'
 get 'article'       => 'articles#show'
 resources :users
 resources :articles do
 resources :comments
 end
 resources :tags
 end
```

Comment: Is this in a test or from a running dev server?

Comment: Please include your ArticlesController create code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is telling you that you're missing the `:id` parameter when attempting to generate the article show route in your `ArticlesController`.

The `resources :articles` line in your `config/routes` file will generate a number of routes helper methods, including `article_path` for the show route. By default, this helper method requires one argument - one that is can translate into the aforementioned `:id` param. This argument should be an article id or, more commonly, an instance of an article. You need to tell Rails to which article show page to send the user, right?

Hence, you need to pass an article instance to your call to `article_path` in your `create` action (and `update` it appears). Here is a rewrite of your `create` action:

```
def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)
  @article.save
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

Comment: That definitely solved the problem for accessing the show but not the real issue. I just figured that the problem is related to the :image for the article to be saved. If I try to load an image, nothing is saved and I get the same issue. If I don t include the image, it gets saved and behaves normally.Anyone has experience working with paperclip?